# How to make SwitchCompat not change colors when checked?

Tags: android, colors, android-styles, tint, switchcompat

This is how it looks like unchecked:

[image: pic]

and checked:

[image: pic]

checked clearly doesn't match design, so how can I make it look like unchecked, when it's checked?

Answer (score 1):

You can tint it with the same color for both statement:

```
    switchButton.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
            isTouched = true;
            switchButton.getThumbDrawable().setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(R.color.your_color), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
            return false;
        }
    });
    switchButton.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked)
        {
            if (isTouched) {
                isTouched = false;
                if (isChecked) {
                    switchButton.getThumbDrawable().setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(R.color.your_color), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
                }
                else {
                    switchButton.getThumbDrawable().setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(R.color.your_color), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: switch'es track doesn't get fixed

Comment: It's untested but try to also add:  switchButton.getTrackDrawable().setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(R.color.your_color), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);

Comment: but how do I make it exactly as it is unchecked? I don't want it to be R.color.y‌​our_color

Answer (score 1):

Got it! I had to do some research, how android finds that darker color for the track...

```
switchview.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked)
        {
            switchview.getThumbDrawable().clearColorFilter();
            int colorPrimaryDark = getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimaryDark);
            int r = (colorPrimaryDark >> 16) & 0xFF;
            int g = (colorPrimaryDark >> 8) & 0xFF;
            int b = (colorPrimaryDark >> 0) & 0xFF;
            r = (r - 30 < 0) ? 0 : r - 30;
            g = (g - 30 < 0) ? 0 : g - 30;
            b = (b - 30 < 0) ? 0 : b - 30;
            int darker = Color.rgb(r, g, b);
            switchview.getTrackDrawable().setColorFilter(darker, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
        }
    });
```

Now checked and unchecked will be exactly the same.